# How do search in some indexes in ElasticSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I use library elastica PHP.
At first before using search I need load index:

```
// Load index
$elasticaIndex = $elasticaClient->getIndex('twit');
```

And after I can do query:

```
$elasticaResultSet = $elasticaIndex->search($elasticaQuery);
```

How to build search to some indexes, not only `twit`?

I use the next:

```
public function Query($value, $elasticaIndex)
    {
        $elasticaQueryString = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
        $elasticaQueryString->setQuery((string)$value);

        // Create the actual search object with some data.
        $elasticaQuery = new \Elastica\Query();
        $elasticaQuery->setQuery($elasticaQueryString);

        //Search on the index.
        $elasticaResultSet = $elasticaIndex->search($elasticaQuery);
        return $elasticaResultSet->getResults();
    }
```

**Adding documents:**

```
private function addDocument($data, $index)
    {
        $this->elasticaIndex = $this->elastic->getIndex($name);
        $this->elasticaIndex->create(array(), true);

        foreach ($data as $id => $val) {
            $documents[] = new \Elastica\Document(
                $id, $val
            );
        }

        $this->elasticaType->addDocuments($documents);
        $this->elasticaType->getIndex()->refresh();
    }
```

Is it right code?

**Creating indexes and mapping:**

For create some indexes I use function wuth param `$name` that means name of index:

```
private function createIndex($name)
    {
        $this->elasticaIndex = $this->elastic->getIndex($name);
        $this->elasticaIndex->create(array(
            'number_of_shards' => 4,
            'number_of_replicas' => 1,
            'analysis' => array(
                'analyzer' => array(
                    $name.'Analyzer' => array(
                        'type' => 'custom',
                        'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                        'filter' => array('lowercase', 'mySnowball')
                    ),
                    $name.'Analyzer' => array(
                        'type' => 'custom',
                        'tokenizer' => 'standard',
                        'filter' => array('standard', 'lowercase', 'mySnowball')
                    )
                )
                /*'filter' => array(
                    'mySnowball' => array(
                        'type' => 'snowball',
                        'language' => 'German'
                    )
                )*/
            )
        ), true);

        $this->elasticaType = $this->elasticaIndex->getType($name);
    }
```

Please, notice attention on `'analyzer' => array()` in `create()` method. It needs for mapping.

Also I have constructor, that creates mapping. For this constructor I pass `$elasticaType` is name of `index_analyzer`, `search_analyzer` from created indexes above.

```
 function __construct($elasticaType)
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $elasticaIndex = $this->elastic->getIndex($elasticaType);
    $elasticaType = $elasticaIndex->getType($elasticaType);

    $this->mapping = new \Elastica\Type\Mapping();
    $this->mapping->setType($elasticaType);
    $this->mapping->setParam('index_analyzer', $elasticaType.'Analyzer');
    $this->mapping->setParam('search_analyzer', $elasticaType.'Analyzer');
}
```

When I try to create mapping I get error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Elastica\Exception\ResponseException' with message 'MapperParsingException[Analyzer [Analyzer] not found for index_analyzer setting on root type [users]]' in
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search in several index with the `\Elastica\Search` class. Here is the version updated of your code :

```
public function Query($value, $elasticaClient)
{
    $elasticaQueryString = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
    $elasticaQueryString->setQuery((string)$value);

    // Create the actual search object with some data.
    $elasticaQuery = new \Elastica\Query();
    $elasticaQuery->setQuery($elasticaQueryString);

    //Search
    $search = new \Elastica\Search($elasticaClient);
    $search->addIndex('twit');
    $search->addIndex('an_other_index');
    $elasticaResultSet = $search->search($elasticaQuery);

    return $elasticaResultSet->getResults();
}
```

Since you are searching on several index, you don't need to pass your `$elasticaIndex` variable, but instead your `$elasticaClient`.

If you want to keep the `$elasticaIndex` way (for some technical reasons), you can achieve what you want to do this way :

```
public function Query($value, $elasticaIndex)
{
    $elasticaQueryString = new \Elastica\Query\QueryString();
    $elasticaQueryString->setQuery((string)$value);

    // Create the actual search object with some data.
    $elasticaQuery = new \Elastica\Query();
    $elasticaQuery->setQuery($elasticaQueryString);

    //Search
    $search = $elasticaIndex->createSearch();
    $search->addIndex('an_other_index');
    $elasticaResultSet = $search->search($elasticaQuery);

    return $elasticaResultSet->getResults();
}
```

---

For your last question with analyzers, you override the var `$elasticaType` when you does :

```
$elasticaType = $elasticaIndex->getType($elasticaType);
```

You should instead do something like this :

```
 function __construct($name)
 {
    parent::__construct();
    $elasticaIndex = $this->elastic->getIndex($name);
    $elasticaType = $elasticaIndex->getType($name);

    $this->mapping = new \Elastica\Type\Mapping();
    $this->mapping->setType($elasticaType);
    $this->mapping->setParam('index_analyzer', $name.'Analyzer');
    $this->mapping->setParam('search_analyzer', $name.'Analyzer');
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78429/discussion-on-answer-by-raphael-malie-how-do-search-in-some-indexes-in-elasticse).